# How to calculate factorials using recursion in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, factorial

I know this code to use in order to find the factorial of any number but what if we wanted it to do more and change up the code, so that it can calculate and print the factorials of number less that 100 recursively. How should this code be modified? Should i use for loop or some other technique?

Answer (score 8):

Try this code, as suggested by [LornaJane](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-recursive-function-example-factorial-numbers):

```
function factorial($number) {          
    if ($number < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 
}
```

Comment: but can we change it up so that it calculates recursively?

Comment: What exactly you mean??

Comment: This is the definition of recursive (recursive: adj. see recursive)

Comment: Now it will calculate recursively

Comment: Simple code for factorial nuber <?php 


 function factorial($num){
 if($num >=1){
  return ($num*factorial($num-1));
 }else {
  return 1;
 } 
} 
$num = 5;
echo factorial($num);